# Function attached as a click handler being called before it is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a simple application that dynamically graphs variables in a line chart using a local data structure. Variable names are displayed along with their corresponding colors in a legend below the line chart. All pretty standard.

I am trying to add functionality by which the user can remove an individual variable from the line chart by clicking on that variable's name in the legend. I tried to do this by using jQuery to attach a click handler as follows:

```
$('.legendItem').click(removeVariable);
```

However in order to remove the variable from the underlying data structure, `removeVariable()` needs the variable name. I am storing this in a `data` attribute in the `.legendItem` span. This way, I can access the attribute with `$('.legendItem').data('keyword')` Since there can be many different `.legendItem` elements, I hoped to pass the data-keyword attribute dynamically to the removeVariable() function for each clicked element.

However I am having trouble when I try to add this passing of data to the click handler. When I add 'keyword' as a parameter to `removeVariable()` and include:

```
$('.legendItem').click(removeVariable($(this).data('keyword')));
```

When I debug through in the Chrome JS debugger, the removeVariable() function is called by the second example but not the first. Since the click handler relies on data that does not exist at this stage of script, it causes an error. Are there any obvious mistakes I'm overlooking or better ways of doing this sort of dynamic manipulation?

Comment: parenthesis after a function reference call that function reference immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are executing the `removeVariable` function instead of passing a reference to it. You can avoid that by using an anonymous function:

```
$('.legendItem').click(function() {
    removeVariable($(this).data('keyword'));
});
```